# Using javascript to load a css hidden image as a background image on page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, background-image, onload

Noob at javascript and have searched without luck. Is it possible to use javascript to load an image which is already in the body of the html (css visibility hidden) to become visible as a background image in a div on page load?

Comment: Test it, you'll find out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Just do like

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      window.onload = function() {

          // get the image url from the src attribute of image
          imgurl =  document.getElementById("yourImgID").src;
          // set it as background to the div you want
          document.getElementById("yourDivID").style.background = "url("+imgurl+") no-repeat";

      }

</script>
```

You can see a sample fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mithunsatheesh/ACSAX/)

Comment: Thanks buddy! What took me a day of searching, you did minutes!